# Bind a <select> to an array in knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a checkbox list on a page that is bound to a knockout observableArray.

When checkboxes are selected knockout updates the observableArray as expected to something like [123, 345, 456] (if three options in that checkbox list are selected)

It then fires off a few functions that goes through the array and does a bunch of things.

My trouble is I want to be able to easily switch between using a checkbox list and a `<select>`. So basically single select vs multiselect, using the same ko.observable...

These extra functions don't work when it's a flat string and not an array.

When using the `<select>`, is there any way I can get the observable to function as a single value array?

E.g using this select...

```
<select data-bind="value: myObservable">
```

I want to make the selected value in myObservable to be:

```
["123"] (or [123])
```

instead of a plain string

```
"123"
```

Comment: you can use `selectedOptions` check this sample http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25655/ . let me know

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Should have put it as an answer so I could give you a green tick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [selectedOptions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) binding instead of `value`.

```
<select data-bind="selectedOptions: myObservable">
```

If you need multiple selection you can use `multiple="true"`:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8b7myy6/2/)